# How to break for every Item, but not the complete root?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, word-wrap

I need to have a Treeview in WPF (C#) with Vertical Wrapping for all TreeView-Items. So far, I got it to work for root items: When the control gets smaller in height, they, and all of their childs get broken. But I want a behaviour that the child TreeView-Items get broken too. Please look at those examples as it's not easy to explain in words:

Example Tree:

```
rootitem1
     child1
     child2
rootitem2
     child3
     child4
```

If the controls height size gets decreased, the Tree wrap looks like this:

```
rootitem1    rootitem2
    child1       child3
    child2       child4
```

But I want the wrapping affects every single Item, even the childs, so the Tree would look like this:

```
rootitem1        child4
    child1
    child2
rootitem2
    child3
```

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="tv_test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <!-- expand items -->
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <!-- example items -->
            <TreeViewItem Header="rootitem1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="child1"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="child2"></TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="rootitem2">
                <TreeViewItem Header="child3"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="child4"></TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <!-- vertical wrap which should break every item, but actually only breaks root items -->
            <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemsPanel>            
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution , I think you would have to pragmatically do what you intend .

mean while this provides half the functionality .

```
    <TreeView  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
          <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <WrapPanel  Orientation="Vertical" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </TreeView.ItemsPanel>

        <!-- expand items -->
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <!-- example items -->
        <TreeViewItem Header="rootitem1">
            <TreeViewItem.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem.ItemsPanel>

            <TreeViewItem Header="child1"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="child2"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="rootitem2">
            <TreeViewItem.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem.ItemsPanel>

            <TreeViewItem Header="child3"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="child4"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>

        <!-- vertical wrap which should break every item, but actually only breaks root items -->

    </TreeView>
```